# Get Class property by its name

Tags: matlab, reflection

Is it possible to reach a Class Property by its name dynamically?

```
classdef ClassA < handle        
    properties
        a
    end        
end

obj = ClassA;
obj.GetVar('a') = 10;
```

Is there something like `GetVar('a')`?

Comment: Did you try `obj.('a')`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 ways to access a field of a struct or a custom object `obj` when its name is given by a string `str` (that I know of). The following are all equivalent to `obj.a`, given `str='a'`:

1. using [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) **(not recommended!)**:

   ```
   eval(['obj.',str])
   ```
2. using [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) (or [`subsasgn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html) for assignment):

   ```
   S = substruct('.',str);
   subsref(obj,S)
   ```
3. using [`getfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html):

   ```
   getfield(obj,str)
   ```
4. using the [functional form of the dot operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html):

   ```
   obj.(str)
   ```

The latter is of course to be preferred.

`subsref` and `subsasgn` are interesting because they are the methods you would overload in your class to modify the behavior of indexing. The `getfield` method has very limited uses, but once was the only sane way of accessing fields using dynamic names, before the `obj.(str)` syntax was introduced.